# Pagination broken on LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I have changed my pagination since it does not have First/Previous and Next/Last navigation functionality to a version that does.

The reason I changed it was because there would be 30+ numbered links at the bottom of the page and it was ugly and looked unprofessional.

The pagination works for all my pages except for two sections on the website. The strange thing is that those two pages have **LEFT JOIN** just as in the sample below, but the difference is that they rely on the selection of a **categoryID** for each to display the data.

[image: Working Pagination]

Below is a sample of the new code for PHP & MySQL and the HTML for the code.

**WORKING PHP & MySQL**

```
//PAGINATION
try {
    $totalPages  = $DB->query(" SELECT COUNT(id) as rows 
                                FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                WHERE articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                AND art_categories.categoryID NOT IN
                                    (SELECT categoryID
                                     FROM art_categories
                                     WHERE categoryID=8)
                                AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                AND state = 1")
              ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $posts  = $totalPages->rows;
    $pages  = ceil($posts / $perpage);

    # default
    $get_pages = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

    $data = array(

        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
            'max_range' => $pages
            )
    );

    $number = trim($get_pages);
    $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $data);
    $range  = $perpage * ($number - 1);

    $prev = $number - 1;
    $next = $number + 1;

    $stmt = $DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH ) LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
    $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

**WORKING HTML**

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php

            if($result && count($result) > 0)
            { ?>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page'] >= 2) { echo('class=""'); } else { echo('class="disabled"'); } ?> >
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('#');} else { echo ('index.php?page=1'); } ?>">FIRST</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if(!empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a <?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?> href="<?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('#');} else { echo ('index.php?page='. $prev); } ?>">&laquo; PREVIOUS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $get_pages; ?>"><?php echo $get_pages; ?></a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('#');} else { echo ('index.php?page='. $next); } ?>">NEXT &raquo;</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('#');} else { echo ('index.php?page='. $pages); } ?>">LAST</a>
            </li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Now everything is fine up to this point. Once I try to do a left LEFT JOIN on other pages for Categories and Advertisers my pagination doesn't function.

I get the following error code:

**Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp64\www\Bushvelder\categories.php on line 15**

This is line 15 in the code:

```
if($result && count($result) > 0)
```

I will include the code below for the Categories page as I believe once I get this sorted I will be able to fix the Advertisers page pagination as well.

**Broken PHP & MySQL**

```
$catID = $_GET['categoryID'];

//PAGINATION
try {
    $totalPages  = $DB->query(" SELECT COUNT(id) as rows 
                                FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                WHERE articles.categoryID={$catID}
                                AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                AND state = Publish")
              ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $posts  = $totalPages->rows;
    $pages  = ceil($posts / $perpage);

    # default
    $get_pages = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

    $data = array(

        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
            'max_range' => $pages
            )
    );

    $number = trim($get_pages);
    $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $data);
    $range  = $perpage * ($number - 1);

    $prev = $number - 1;
    $next = $number + 1;

    $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                            FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                            ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                            WHERE articles.categoryID={$catID}
                            AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                            AND state = Publish
                            ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
    $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php

        if($result && count($result) > 0)
        { ?>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page'] >= 2) { echo('class=""'); } else { echo('class="disabled"'); } ?> >
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('#');} else { echo ('categories.php?categoryID='. $article['categoryID'] . '&amp;page=1'); } ?>">FIRST</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if(!empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a <?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?> href="<?php if($_GET['page']==1 || $_GET['page']==0) { echo('#');} else { echo ('categories.php?'. $article['categoryID'] . '&amp;page='. $prev); } ?>">&laquo; PREVIOUS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="categories.php?categoryID=<?php echo $article['categoryID']; ?>&amp;page=<?php echo $get_pages; ?>"><?php echo $get_pages; ?></a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('#');} else { echo ('categories.php?'. $article['categoryID'] . '&amp;page='. $next); } ?>">NEXT &raquo;</a>
            </li>
            <li <?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('class="disabled"');} ?>>
                <a href="<?php if($_GET['page']==$pages) { echo('#');} else { echo ('categories.php?'. $article['categoryID'] . '&amp;page='. $pages); } ?>">LAST</a>
            </li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

I strongly suspect I messed up with my MySQL, but I do not know where to go from here. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

If I figure it out before this is answered I will post my findings.

---

**EDIT**

Okay so I fixed the mistake with **LIMIT :limit, :perpage**, but I still get the error on line 15 as stated above.

Comment: As i suspect you aren't binding anything with LIMIT. and passing variable through bindparam

Comment: You need to pass param like  LIMIT :perpage :limit

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did to solve my problem.

**FIRST**
I did some variable dumping with **var_dump($variable)** for all the variables related to my pagination problem.

```
<?php echo var_dump($result); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($totalPages); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($pages); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($get_pages); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($posts); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($stmt); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($catID); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($article['categoryID']); ?>
<?php echo var_dump($_GET['page']); ?>
```

This gave me valuable insights into what variables had values in them and which were null.

I then went to my original code:

```
$stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                        FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                        ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                        WHERE articles.categoryID={$catID}
                        AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                        AND state = Publish
                        ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
$stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

I then setup various *SWITCH CASES* via PHP to see if the **categoryID** was indeed changing when I clicked on my menu. And this was indeed functioning.

```
switch ($catID) {
        case 1:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT art_categories.*, articles.*
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=1
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 2:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=2
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 3:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=3
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 4:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=4
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 5:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=5
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 6:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=6
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 7:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=7
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
        case 8:
            $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                                    FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                    ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                    WHERE articles.categoryID=8
                                    AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                                    AND state = Publish
                                    ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
            break;
    }
```

I then reviewed the **VAR_DUMP** data and the $result variable still posted as null. So I decided to check out my queries. I went through many iterations of query code trying different methods of **JOIN** to see how it affected my **VAR_DUMP** data.

This then showed me that the **LEFT JOIN** I had originally use in my MySQL queries had no issues, as it was functioning with the other pages where **LEFT JOIN** was used.

I proceeded to test my queries until success at last!

```
$catID = $_GET['categoryID'];

//PAGINATION
try {

    $totalPages  = $DB->query(" SELECT COUNT(id) as rows 
                                FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                                ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                                WHERE articles.categoryID = {$catID}
                                AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )")
              ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $posts  = $totalPages->rows;
    $pages  = ceil($posts / $perpage);

    # default
    $get_pages = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

    $data = array(

        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
            'max_range' => $pages
            )
    );

    $number = trim($get_pages);
    $number = filter_var($number, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $data);
    $range  = $perpage * ($number - 1);

    $prev = $number - 1;
    $next = $number + 1;

    $stmt = $DB->prepare("  SELECT *
                            FROM art_categories LEFT JOIN articles
                            ON articles.categoryID=art_categories.categoryID
                            WHERE articles.categoryID = {$catID}
                            AND articles.publishDate >= DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH )
                            ORDER BY articles.publishDate DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
    $stmt->bindParam(':perpage', $perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $range, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

So after all the testing it seems that *AND state = Publish* was the culprit that broke my pagination and resulted in hours of frustration, wasted time and had scratching. It seems there was a problem with the *ENUM* I had created to check if the content is saved as in a DRAFT or PUBLISH state.

***What have I learned from this?***

- Stay calm and don't panic
- Use **var_dump()** to test your variables
- Setting up different **CASE SWITCHES** really helped me
- Troubleshoot your problems properly
- Don't give up
- Learned some new tricks